# else if statement defaulting to the last condition vba

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I'm currently writing a macro that will read a column of dates, check the month of each item, record the number in a variable, and put the final number in a cell. The program is looking through a column of 2999 items. The column isn't completely full. The number was selected because the number of items COULD be that high.

The for each loop checks which month each cell is and increases that month's variable by 1. However at the end, the December variable is around 2500. There are only about 500 filled rows. The sum of the months comes to 2999 (the number of rows being searched). I'm not sure why it's doing this. I tried adding an "else" condition. It's not even reaching that far. A15 is never filled with "Batman". I have to be missing something simple. Help?

```
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim JanCount As Integer
Dim FebCount As Integer
Dim MarCount As Integer
Dim AprCount As Integer
Dim MayCount As Integer
Dim JunCount As Integer
Dim JulCount As Integer
Dim AugCount As Integer
Dim SepCount As Integer
Dim OctCount As Integer
Dim NovCount As Integer
Dim DecCount As Integer
Dim dateValue As Date
Dim monthInt As Integer

Set rng3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K2:K3000")

For Each cell In rng3
dateValue = cell.Value
monthInt = month(dateValue)

If monthInt = 1 Then
    JanCount = JanCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 2 Then
    FebCount = FebCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 3 Then
    MarCount = MarCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 4 Then
    AprCount = AprCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 5 Then
    MayCount = MayCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 6 Then
    JunCount = JunCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 7 Then
    JulCount = JulCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 8 Then
    AugCount = AugCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 9 Then
    SepCount = SepCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 10 Then
    OctCount = OctCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 11 Then
    NovCount = NovCount + 1

ElseIf monthInt = 12 Then
    DecCount = DecCount + 1

Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A15") = "Batman"

End If

Next cell

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10") = "Bugs in Jan"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10") = "Bugs in Feb"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10") = "Bugs in Mar"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10") = "Bugs in Apr"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E10") = "Bugs in May"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F10") = "Bugs in Jun"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G10") = "Bugs in Jul"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H10") = "Bugs in Aug"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J10") = "Bugs in Oct"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K10") = "Bugs in Nov"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L10") = "Bugs in Dec"

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A11") = JanCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B11") = FebCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11") = MarCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D11") = AprCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11") = MayCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F11") = JunCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G11") = JulCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H11") = AugCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I11") = SepCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J11") = OctCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K11") = NovCount
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L11") = DecCount
```

Comment: Cell A15 is not Batman! I'M BATMAN!

Comment: If you post your input we may have more to work with @AndyArduesser

Comment: can you place a `MsgBox cell.Value` above line `dateValue = cell.Value`? run the code and please tell us what the message box has shown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace the line

```
Set rng3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K2:K3000")
```

with

```
Set rng3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K2:K" & Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Basically as **S. Wirth** said, it is because of the blank cells. So in the above code, instead of making it loop till 3000, i am just making it take till whatever data is there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A warning: This assumes that there are no blank cells between the first and last cells. If there will be, blank cells still need to be skipped.

Comment: this should have been an advice or comment. it does't solve the problem. why would you post it as an answer?

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you. This actually did solve the problem and worked perfectly. I'm exporting my data from a database. Maybe it defaults empty cell dates to 12? No idea. But this removes the potential to run into that problem. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I am sorry guys. Even i think Jens Fischer's answer should be marked as answer as that is the correct way of doing it. I didn't think about blank cells as in the question, it is specifically mentioned that there are '500 filled rows'. My main intention was making Andy understand why this was happening. And I think he did. It doesn't matter to me if mine was marked answer or not. Apologies if i did this the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

Try to first check with `IsDate()` whether the cell value can be interpreted as a date.

And.. just a suggestion to make the whole thing a little bit easier:

```
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim BugCount(1 To 12)


Set Rng3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K2:K3000")

For Each cell In Rng3
    If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        BugCount(Month(cell.Value)) = BugCount(Month(cell.Value)) + 1
    End If
Next

For monthctr = 1 To 12
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Offset(0, monthctr - 1).Value = "Bugs in " & Format(DateSerial(2013, monthctr, 1), "MMM")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A11").Offset(0, monthctr - 1).Value = BugCount(monthctr)

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

if your cell is empty, then the date value of the cell is 0. The date value 0 is defined as January 0, 1900 and so you get 1 as result of the month() function.
First of all check if the cell.Value is null.

regards
Stephan

Comment: I actually got 12 as the result of the month() when testing

Comment: I was getting the unusual number from the empty cells. They must have defaulted to 12 for some reason. I'm not sure. The data is exported from a database and may have formatted strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the month of blank cells are always returned as 12 for some reason. Try changing the december line to:

```
ElseIf monthInt = 12 And cell.value <> "" Then
```

Comment: Obviously an answer, since it's tested and working. And yes, I've stepped through.